# How to get variable's value outside a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am beginer learning first steps with JS. Today i got problem with Variable. I can't get the variable's value outside a function.

First i have this html

```
    <label for="inputValue">Input here</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputValue">
    <button id="addbtn">Button</button>
    <h4 id="result"></h4>
```

and scripts like this:

```
<script>
var inputValue = ""; 
var outputArr = []; 
//I want to get input text by clicking the button

document.getElementbyId('addbtn').addEventListener('click', function() { 
    inputValue = document.getElementById('inputValue').value;
    outputArr.push(inputValue); 
});

console.log(outputArr);

</script>
```

I want to get outputArr's value which being got inside the function but the console.log print the variable's value before changed, pls help me..

Comment: Why don't you just access `outputArr` inside the event handler?

Comment: The outside `console.log()` is called once at the same time that the listener is added. It has no relation to the listener callback whatsoever. If you want to log on click you need to do so in the handler callback. Or, since it is a global variable inside any other listener.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried to put console.log command inside the event listener, and i receive exactly what i wanted, but i need to use that value in others place, so how can i do?

Comment: your code is good, you are getting vaule in outputArr but you are checking at wrong place.

Comment: You can simply use the value in other places. If you access `outpuArr` in another listener assigned say to another button, then clicking one button and then the other will use the updated value. The main thing to keep in mind is that the listener is preparing for a future event which may or may not occur, it is not mutating the value directly.

Comment: @pilchard thanks you. i deeply understand your explaination. So, when i assign value to a variable inside a function, not only event listener, how can i get that value outside the box?

Comment: @VietTienDo use your array outputArr, just that its value will be updated after button click. also use () => {} in place of function() callback

Answer (score 0):

As you told that the problem is timing, i tried to fix them by separated the code into two listener, mousedown and mouseup, here is what i thought:

```
document.getElementById('addbtn').addEventListener('mousedown', function() { 
inputValue = document.getElementById('inputValue').value; 
outputArr.push(inputValue);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = outputArr;  
// console.log(outputArr); //Give me exactly the result i wanted. 
}); 

// console.log(outputValue); //This don't give me result because it ran immediately after i set up event listener.
```

// but this can give me the answer

```
document.getElementById('addbtn').addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    console.log(outputValue); 
});
```

How do you guys think?